# Memory leak synchronous reading interrupt transfer data via libUSB

Tags: c, windows, memory-leaks, usb, libusb

I discovered a memory leak reading data via USB interrupt transfer using libUSB synchronously. My simple user program is not using any dynamic memory allocation itself. Internally libusb makes excessive use of dynamic memory allocation. The communication flow is working as expected. Is there a special function to free any internal dynamic memory after using libusb_interrupt_transfer? Does anyone have an idea what causes the continously increase of memory during runtime?

[image]

My protocol implements a two way handshake. Because of this a simple data exchange causes a OUT(request), IN(Ack/Nack), IN(Response) and OUT(Ack/Nack) transfer. The report size is 32 Bytes, the outEndpointAddr is 1, the inEndpointAddr is 129, Here are the relevant code snippets.

```
int main (void)
{
    uint32_t devFound = 0;
    uint32_t devErrors = 0;

    ...
    
    int libUsbErr = 0;
    if(!findSensor(&devFound, &devErrors, &libUsbErr, foundCB))
        printf("finding sensor failed %d\n", libUsbErr);
    
    if(!openSensor(mySensor, &libUsbErr))
        printf("open sensor failed %d\n", libUsbErr);
    
    int i = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("[%06d] Int Temp %f C\n",i++, readIntTemper());
        Delay(0.5);
    }
    closeSensor(&mySensor, NULL);
    
    closeSensorContext();
    return 0;
}

float readIntTemper()
{
    static uint8_t tmp[32];  
    static uint8_t response[32];  
    
    ...//Prepare request frame
    
    int libUsbErr = 0;
    if(!HID_Write(mySensor, tmp, &written, 4000, &libUsbErr))
    {
        printf("write request failed %d\n", libUsbErr);
        return 0;
    }

    //Read Ack / Nack
    if(!HID_Read(mySensor, tmp, &read, 4000, &libUsbErr))
    {
        printf("Read ACK NACK failed %d\n", libUsbErr);
        return 0;
    }
    
    ...//Test if Ack / Nack

    
    if(!HID_Read(mySensor, response, &read, 4000, &libUsbErr))
    {
        printf("Read response failed %d\n", libUsbErr);
        return 0;
    }            

    ... //Prepare ACK
    
    if(!HID_Write(mySensor, tmp, &written, 4000, &libUsbErr))
    {
        printf("Ack response failed %d\n", libUsbErr);
        return 0;
    }

    ...

    float* temper = (float*)&response[8];
    return *temper;
}

bool HID_Write(const Sensor* sens, uint8_t* repBuf, int* transferred, uint32_t timeout, int* libUsbErr)
{
    if(sens == NULL || repBuf == NULL || transferred == NULL)
        return returnlibUSBErr(libUsbErr, -1008); ///TODO nice error codes;
        
    if(!sens->claimed)
        return returnlibUSBErr(libUsbErr, -1012); ///TODO nice error codes;
    
    int r = libusb_interrupt_transfer(sens->devHandle, sens->outEndpointAddr, 
                          repBuf, sens->outRepSize, transferred, timeout); 
    if (r < 0) 
        return returnlibUSBErr(libUsbErr, r); 
    return returnlibUSBErr(libUsbErr, LIB_USB_OK);
}

bool HID_Read(const Sensor* sens, uint8_t* repBuf, int* read, uint32_t timeout, int* libUsbErr)            
{    
    if(sens == NULL || read == NULL)
        return returnlibUSBErr(libUsbErr, -1008); ///TODO nice error codes;
    
    if(!sens->claimed)
        return returnlibUSBErr(libUsbErr, -1012); ///TODO nice error codes;     
    
    int r = libusb_interrupt_transfer(sens->devHandle, sens->inEndpointAddr, repBuf,sens->inRepSize, read, timeout); 
    if (r < 0) 
        return returnlibUSBErr(libUsbErr, r); 
    return returnlibUSBErr(libUsbErr, LIB_USB_OK);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If followed this instruction to monitor memory usage:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-performance-monitor-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak

To find the leak I used UMDH Windows tool like mentioned here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-umdh-to-find-a-user-mode-memory-leak

The problem is that I have to use CVI NI compilter to build my application. I wasn't able to get the symbol table out of this compilter. So my heap dump diff only shows addresses.

```
// Each log entry has the following syntax:                                 
//                                                                          
// + BYTES_DELTA (NEW_BYTES - OLD_BYTES) NEW_COUNT allocs BackTrace TRACEID 
// + COUNT_DELTA (NEW_COUNT - OLD_COUNT) BackTrace TRACEID allocations      
//     ... stack trace ...                                                  
//                                                                          
// where:                                                                   
//                                                                          
//     BYTES_DELTA - increase in bytes between before and after log         
//     NEW_BYTES - bytes in after log                                       
//     OLD_BYTES - bytes in before log                                      
//     COUNT_DELTA - increase in allocations between before and after log   
//     NEW_COUNT - number of allocations in after log                       
//     OLD_COUNT - number of allocations in before log                      
//     TRACEID - decimal index of the stack trace in the trace database     
//         (can be used to search for allocation instances in the original  
//         UMDH logs).                                                      
//                                                                          


+   80000 ( 80000 -     0)      1 allocs    BackTrace4920B3C
+       1 (     1 -     0)  BackTrace4920B3C    allocations

    ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+274
    cvirte!LoadExternalModule+291EC
    cvirte!CVIDynamicMemoryInfo+12B6
    cvirte!CVIDynamicMemoryInfo+1528
    cvirte!CVIDynamicMemoryInfo+1AF9
    cvirte!mblen+84D
    cvirte!_CVI_Resource_Acquire+116
    cvirte!malloc+68
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 41DCE8
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 4E95C7
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 4C13BE
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 4BA09D
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 4C7ABA
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 4F92F0
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 4FB3BD
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 4FC50E
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 415C31
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 408847
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 402967
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 41B51E
    libUSB_HID!???+0 : 41A021
    kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+E
    ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+70
```

I also replaced all free, alloc, calloc and realloc cmds within libUSB with my a own implementation tracking every single memory request. This tracking is not showing any memory leak. The amount of allocated bytes stays constant during runtime as expected. Anyway the UMDH tools shows a heap allocation difference. So I'm completely out of ideas what to test next atm.

Comment: Is it C or C++? Delete inappropriate tag.

Comment: And what is your question ? Can you read [mcve] and [ask]?

Comment: I removed the inappropriate tag. Questions: Is there a special function to free any internal dynamic memory after using libusb_interrupt_transfer? Does anyone have an idea what causes the continously increase of memory during runtime?

Comment: How are you are you measuring memory use?

Comment: Via the windows task manager.

Comment: Ahhh ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Would be lovely to use a tool like valgrind but for Windows I know nothing comparable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I ported my program to minGW gcc and everythink is working as expected. It seams that my porting of libusb for CVI compiler is not completely correct. Now I use the standard dll and the memory leak is gone.

Answer (score 1):

> My simple user program is not using any dynamic memory allocation.

Unfortunately, those `libusb_xxx_transfer` functions do stuff with `malloc()` internally. But it is also suppsed to do the corresponding `free()` just before exiting to the caller.

That memory is not normally returned to the OS, but retained in the appliction to be used in the next `malloc()` calls. As a result you will see some memory use in task manager.

That is why you need better tools to detect *actual* memory leaks, like valgrind.